# Highlight search result in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, syntax-highlighting, highlight, cakephp-2.3

as the title says I need to highlight the input string of a search in the results, I mean if I look for "ome" the results should look like this:

1. c **ome**
2. s **ome**
3. Jer **ome**
4. s **ome** one
   etc.

Searching on the documentation I have found that I need to activate the "Text" helper and that I should have a code similar to this:

```
echo $this->Text->highlight($string);
```

Even though I've tried many possibilities, I can not make it work, I know "Text" helper is working because this works for me at View/Users/index.ctp:

```
echo $this->Text->autoLinkEmails(h($user['User']['email']));
```

if it helps, this is the code I've generated for the search which works correctly:

**file: Model/Oldcaterm.php**

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Search.Searchable'
);

public $filterArgs =  array(
        'entry' => array(
        'type' => 'like',
        'field' => array('entry', 'lemma_tag')
        ),
        'lemma_tag' => array(
        'type' => 'like',
        'field' => array('entry', 'lemma_tag')
        ),
);
```

**file: Controller/OldcatermsController.php**

```
public function index() {
        $this->Oldcaterm->recursive = 0;
        $this->Prg->commonProcess();
        $this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $this->Oldcaterm->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams());
        $this->set('terms', $this->Paginator->paginate());
}
```

**file: View/Oldcaterms/index.ctp**

```
<?php
        echo $this->Form->create(null,array());
        echo $this->Form->input('entry', array('label' => 'Cerca coincidència'));
        echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));
?>
```

I have read and try many differents ways, but I'm not able to make it work, can somebody please guide me a little, I have found next example at the documentation:

```
// called as TextHelper
echo $this->Text->highlight(
 $lastSentence,
 'using',
 array('format' => '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
);

// called as String
App::uses('String', 'Utility');
echo String::highlight(
 $lastSentence,
 'using',
 array('format' => '<span class="highlight">\1</span>')
);
```

But I don't find the way to make it fit into my code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You better refer to the official docs, and not some 4 1/2 years old blog post: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/text.html#TextHelper::highlight

Comment: sorry, I have read that also, but due to my lack of knowledge in cake (i'm a newbe) I didn't understand the documentation you advice, That's why I look for an alternative source, any help though?

Comment: Well, what is it that you don't understand about it? It's just a simple method call, the first argument to pass is the content, the second one is the string to highlight, and the optional third one can be used to define the HTML wrapper to use for the highlighted strings. It even has a copy & paste ready example, there's really not much more to explain. If you have any specific problems with it, then you'll need to elaborate that.

Comment: Ok, the concept I can grab it, but I don't know where to put each thing, I don't know how to write the apropriate code

Comment: Sorry, I was long time gone, now retaking issues, well the thing is that I can not find the way to apply this to my code, I've tried many different ways but no success, So what I need is a bit of help in locating things where they belong, thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get what exactly you are having problems with. "_Locating things where they belong_" is a way to generic description of whatever causes you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

After a few studies, I realized the **css style is not there**. Right click on your browser and **explore the source code**, if it shows `<span class="highlight">Your Text Here</span>` then everything is **just right**. Just add followings code to your **CSS file**

`.highlight{
    background-color: #FFDF00; /* <-- Choose what colour you want to use. Here is Golden Yellow  */
 }`

If you still have any problem, **please share** in the comment.